# Fill ASP.NET form automatically an GET result from not own page

Tags: asp.net, forms

im new here. I just want ask if by your decissions or experiences after see the code is possible to fill form on page by my own script and GET result for another work (finding special string).

page is `https://cica.vugk.sk/LV_vyber.aspx` it is freeware database of owners of lands, flat, houses in Slovakia.

In image you can see filled selects, after click on button you get result that is what I want. Of course in every send request i know values of selects.

Thanks for your advices

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgmHD.jpg)